# How to know which in *format* is a date returned, in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, date

The following code, d has the current date. Depending on the current locale, it will return a date.

```
Dim d As Date = Date.Today
```

Note: I don't want to check whether the date is valid or not, but rather to know, whether it is in a 'dd-MM-yyyy', 'MM-dd-yyyy' or any other date format..

### EDIT (29/06/2012 - Friday):

The reason I am asking this question is because I am sick of *trying* to deal with dates in ASP.NET. I build a project on my local PC, where dates are "dd/MM/yyyy" and as soon as I upload it to the production server (usually in US, hence MM/dd/yyyy) the code breaks.

So I usually deal with dates by converting them into yyyyMMdd format and also keep them in the database like that. That is the closest I get to an exception-free coding.

In this case, it makes sense that there is no way to get the format from a returned date string. Therefore, I will carry on with my approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Date.Today`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today.aspx#Y0) is a [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx), not a string. Thus, it does not have an inherent format.

Comment: Yeesh... because it's too hard to figure out how to use localization?`:/`

Comment: Also because, on shared servers, its difficult to rely on the server owners to keep a specific locale for you...

Answer (score 0):

It will return a `Date`, which I *believe* is a VB alias for [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx). (If it's not, just use `DateTime` explicitly to be idiomatically .NET rather than using the legacy VB types.)

A `DateTime` value itself doesn't have a format, any more than an `int` is in decimal or hex. It's only when you convert the value to a string that a format is applied, and then it depends on *how* you convert it to a string. You shouldn't use a string conversion until you really need to, and then you should control the format so that it works the way you want it to.

As far as possible, convert text data *into* its "natural" type as early as possible, and keep it in that type for as long as possible. For example, avoid converting to strings when passing values in SQL queries - instead, use parameterized SQL where you can specify the parameter value *as* a `DateTime`.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to know is found in:

`CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern`

This is the format string that will be used when you call

`d.ToShortDateString()`

Answer (score -1):

You need to be TOLD; there's no other way. Take for example:

```
6/12/2012
```

It's valid in `dd/mm/yyyy` or `mm/dd/yyyy` format

Which one do you pick if you don't know the locale/format beforehand?

Date values don't have an intrinsic format. In other words, you can format the date to any string representation you need but the opposite conversion from a string back to a Date value requires that you know in which format you are receiving this date string.